# How much benefit we earn with no cost emi on CC

Tags: interest-rate, compound-interest, spreadsheet

I am thinking to take a policy on no cost emi of CC. I want to find money I saved annually by opting to no cost emi against paying all premium lumpsum at the start of the year. I want to consider interest earned on money in saving account which is paid in later months with no cost emi against no interest earned when premium is paid in full.

Savings account are quarterly componding
Annual premium:  ₹6872
Monthly premium: 6872/12= ₹572
Annual Interest rate: 3% = 0.03
Quarterly interest rate:  = 0.03/4

I know the amount is less, but still I want to learn how its done. I want to do learn in both ways, like how it can be done mathematically and in MS Excel.

Below is my attempt.

- 3*572 = ₹1716 amount paid in last three months (months 10, 11 and 12), hence its compounded for 3 quarters, so it becomes (3*572)*(1+0.03/4)^3=1754. Profit = 1754-1716= ₹38
- 3*572 = ₹1716 amount paid in months 7, 8 and 9), hence its compounded for 2 quarters, so it becomes 
  (3*572)*(1+0.03/4)^2=1741. Profit = 1741-1716= ₹25
- 3*572 = ₹1716 amount paid in months 4, 5 and 6), hence its compounded for 1 quarter, so it becomes (3*572)*(1+0.03/4)^1=1728. Profit=1728-1716= ₹12

Is the profit mere 38+25+12 =  ₹75

Also I am not able to calculate the same with FV formula in Excel.

Comment: What the heck is " no cost emi of CC"?

Comment: ohh no cost emi on Credit cards, its zero interest rate emi

Comment: And what's emi, some sort of insurance policy?

Comment: EMI is Equated Monthly Installment